# Cannot send emails via AWS-SES and Sidekiq

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, aws-sdk, sidekiq, amazon-ses

We are migrating from DelayedJob to Sidekiq. And things seem fine, except, we use Amazon's SES to send emails. I believe the issue is one of threadsafe problems.

Whenever we queue up more than 1 email we get tons of errors like these

```
WARN EmailJob::perform IOError closed stream #<SendMailQueueItemWorker:0x00007f7fb00b7ae8 @jid="242cafc31a55b6121959103f"> /usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `wait_readable'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:124:in `read'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:291:in `block in read_body_0'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:276:in `inflater'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:281:in `read_body_0'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:202:in `read_body'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1408:in `block in send_entity'
/mnt/xxx-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.22.1/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/patches.rb:40:in `block in new_transport_request'
```

Or

```
EmailJob::perform OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unexpected record #<SendMailQueueItemWorker:0x000055c08033f748 @jid="47a8cdc65878dcaa9e6ad817"> /usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `ssl_socket_connect'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:928:in `connect'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1384:in `request'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1407:in `send_entity'
/usr/local/rubies/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1195:in `post'
/mnt/xxx-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/aws-ses-feac6b6b069d/lib/aws/ses/base.rb:165:in `request'
/mnt/xxx-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/aws-ses-feac6b6b069d/lib/aws/ses/send_email.rb:103:in `send_raw_email'
```

The code is literally identical to that called from inside of DelayedJob for years without issue.

Is there anything we can do here or do we go back to DJ for Amazon-related calls? We make lots of calls to different Amazon services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to use one global AWS connection in multiple threads.  That's the biggest difference between Sidekiq and DJ: your code must be threadsafe.  Switch to a connection pool.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#connection-pooling

Comment: Aha! Thanks. I am now trying to figure out exactly how to do this.